# Implement search functionality in ASP.NET Core Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, search

I am trying to find a way to implement search in a asp.net core application I am building.
I want to search fields and dates mainly. I came across Elastic search but I am using sql server as my database. I read that Lucene is a search engine library. So my question is, because I want to clarify something. Do i have to create a small custom search engine to build lambda expressions based on my search requests, or i can use something else that exists that can query my database, in my case sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are built-in functions in LINQ for you to use with your query. Such as:

```
var tickets = _dbcontext.tickets.Where(x => x.columnName == "123");
```

Here's an easy example I found: https://dev.to/alexruzenhack/using-c-linq-api-to-perform-sql-in-logic-at-where-clause-i5f

Comment: So i use nested-LINQ queries for multile a complex queries also right?